# Multiple http post requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am working on an Angular js app and all I want to do is to create multiple http post requests in a specific order.

I have Persons and every person has multiple addresses and multiple telephones. So I want to

- Create the addressees in the database with http request
- When it is done, take back the ID of the addresses created in the database
- Do the same for the telephones
- After all this is done, create the Person in the database and referencing the corresponding addresses and telephones hi owns.

What is the proper/best way to do that ? This way it will work but I think there is better alternatives

```
//create the address
$http.post(API_ADDRESS, {
    params: {
        // ...
    }
})
.then(function(res) {
    // create the telephone
    // create the Person in the then function
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: `.then(...).then(...).then(...)`

Comment: Chatty APIs are difficult to work with. You would have much easier time if your user creation endpoint also accepted full details for the addresses and telephones, and created them.

Comment: I think your best option would be to create a post command that can accept all the data you need to save, which creates the addresses, telephones etc in _one_ request.

Comment: `createAddress().then(createTelephone).then(createPerson)`

Comment: In other words, while it _should_ work, don't "chain" requests like that. It'll get messy very quickly.

Comment: `http.post(...).then(createTelephone).then(createPerson).then(createPerson).catch(error)`

Comment: http.post().then(result),,,then()...then()

Comment: as @str suggested you can link various `.then()` to accomplish the sequence calling to the functions, but I wonder, `create the telephone` and `create the Person in the then function` are also calls to the API to affect the database? because the response should be asynchronous so to call the next function you should monitor the response from the previous one... if is the case.

Comment: Many thanks, which solution is the best 1/ .then(...).then(...).then(...)  or 2/ create a post command that can accept all the data in one request ?

Comment: Imo, the combined post command (option 2). The first option will result in quite a mess of callbacks, in the front-end.

Comment: Well, just figured out that even if I get all the details with one post request, I need callbacks on the server side (to get back the ID of the created Address etc..)